# How can I get the HBase table name from a Result object as the mapreduce parameter?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

HBASE-3996
Support multiple tables and scanners as input to the mapper in map/reduce job.
The map function always looks as follows:

```
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context)
```

In the map function, how can I distinguish which table the (Result)value comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the TableSplit from the context, this should work for you (not tested):

```
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) {
    TableSplit currentSplit = (TableSplit)context.getInputSplit();
    byte[] tableName = split.getTableName();
    ....
}
```